# Haskell point-free compilation type

Tags: haskell

So I'm really new to Haskell, but I was playing around with the point free notation and came across this issue. I'm in the console:

```
> let c = (.)negate 
> :t c 
> (a -> Integer) -> a -> Integer -> a
```

but negate takes a Number, so why is it being constrained to an Integer type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is another case of the extended defaulting rules in GHCi.  Do `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` or just do

```
> :set +m  -- multiline input in GHCi
> let c :: (Num a) => (b -> a) -> b -> a -> b
|     c = (.) negate
|
> :t c
Num a => (b -> a) -> b -> a -> b
```

Comment: Just a note, you don't need multi line input; you can write `let x :: T; x = t`.

Comment: @user2407038 You don't need it, and you can also use `:{` and `:}`, but I prefer `:set +m`, it's more like how IPython does multi-line input.